# How can I use the Disqus comments in my three-language site in all three languages different?

Tags: api, comments, disqus

How can I use the Disqus comments in my three-language site in all three languages different? I saved one language and I cannot use else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing [this doc](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466249), there are a couple of ways to have a multi-lingual site:

1. Create as many Disqus shortnames as you need languages, and reference those shortnames in each language portion of your site where you load Disqus
2. Use the following javascript override to load different languages per-page:

   var disqus_config = function () { 
     this.language = "ru";
   };

Use option #1 if you want to moderate or manage each language separately. Option #2 is good if those moderating can do so in either language.